# convert ImageMagick command line argument to Wand

Tags: imagemagick, wand

I'm wondering how to convert this working command line sequence for ImageMagick into a Python script using the Wand library:

```
convert test.gif -fuzz 5% -layers Optimize test5.gif
```

Python code is:

```
from wand.api import library
from wand.color import Color
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.image import Image
import ctypes
library.MagickSetImageFuzz.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p,
                                       ctypes.c_double)
with Image(filename='test.gif') as img:
    library.MagickSetImageFuzz(img.wand, img.quantum_range * 0.05)
    with Drawing() as ctx:
        ctx(img)
    img.optimize_layers()
    img.save(filename='test5.gif')
```

But, I got a different result from the ImageMagick command line.
Why...

Comment: Nice first question JunZhang. Could you provide the output from ImageMagick and your python script respectively. It makes it easier for anyone trying to help you to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This matches the CLI, but results may vary if the gif is animated or previously optimized.

```py
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='test.gif') as img:
    img.fuzz = img.quantum_range * 0.05
    img.optimize_layers()
    img.save(filename='test5.gif')
```